# Unity 3D Model imported with offset Mesh

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes, importing

So I've edited up an image to help show the problem, since showing the game itself is not an option:

[image]

When I imported my model, the model appears normally, however when I actually put it into the scene, a duplicate of the mesh appears, off to the left and partially lower (as shown with the edited image above) and normally I would ignore it, however it's causing some issues with the camera, causing it to rotate outside of the model, and I'm guessing it's because this mesh is the center of the model.

I've been using Unity on and off for a few years but in all that time, I've never had this happen. Is it from how the model is imported, or something to do with the model itself? All the models in my game are 100% custom made, there are no assets. I'm really not sure what caused this or how to fix it.

edit: The green mesh is not visible when the game runs, you only see it in the editor.

This effect cannot be recreated with any other model, which is why I had the edited screenshot but just to show you the exact same thing with the above screenshot but in Unity with 2 models. The pink one is the regular model (just picture a different pose) and the green one being the mesh.
[image]

Again, the custom made model for this game is the only model I have seen do this and because I am not allowed to upload said model or even images vaguely resembling it, that is why I used the screenshot in the first place.

Comment: If you can't show us the real effect, we'll have a much harder time helping you. Can you reproduce the problem in a new, empty project that does not contain any confidential material, so you can share unaltered screenshots here?

Comment: Which 3d modelling software did you use? What is scaling system of your software? How did you export? It couldn't be unity issue but its an exportation issue.

Comment: @SaadAnees I'm using blender 2.79, I'm not sure about the scaling system as that's the first I've ever heard of that. I saved the model as a .blend file then drag and drop that into Unity (same as I've done with every other model) and never had this problem before. 

The only difference between this model and my other models, is that it uses only 2 textures and 2 materials, whereas the others had a texture and material for each individual item.

Comment: @DMGregory I've taken a screenshot of Unity with the model in it, and I've placed a screenshot of another model recreating the same effect visually in the center. It shows the settings and should be more helpful now.

Comment: It looks like you have both a mesh collider and a capsule collider active — is this intentional?

Comment: @DMGregory Usually it's the only way to stop it from falling through the floor whenever I apply a rigidbody to it.